# How to use PrepareBitmap method for all the different sizes

Tags: android, bitmap, view, drawable

The question is this: I have a picture I want to use it in a costum view, so I have to use the Preparebitmap methode where I have to specify the picutres which I want to draw and the Width/Height that the picture will take.

I created the image for all the sizes, I mean there's the same picture with different resulotion (I placed them in the drawable folders (ldpi, mdpi...)); so the main question is how to draw the bitmap to be shown perfectly with all the screen, maybe the following example will clear my problem:

```
 appLogo = prepareBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.applogo), 100, 100);
```

the bitmap will be drawn in 100X100 space, so in bigger screens, the image will be small, even if it exist in the xx-hdpi folder. Is there any way how to get the real size of the image whatever the screen was ? I want something like:

```
appLogo = prepareBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.applogo), Height, Width);
```

with Height/Width are the real Height/Width of the image.

Thank you

Comment: Can you just put this image into an imageView and display it?

Comment: Yes I can, but you know, what if I want something else? like, what I need to use the onTouchEvent or something like that? you follow me...

Comment: No, not really... you can capture image touches by overriding the on touch event of an ImageView.  Need to understand why the standard doesn't work for you, to recommend anything else.